# Read all the subsequent chars and transform into an int

Tags: c, string

I'm reading a txt file and getting all the chars that aren't space, transforming them to int using `(int)c-'0'` and that is working.

The problem is if the number has more than 1 digit, because I'm reading char by char.

How could I do to read like a sequence of chars, transform this sequence of chars into int?

I tried using a string, but when I try to pass this string to my other function, it treats each index as a number, but what I need is that the whole string is treated as one number.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A convenient way to do the conversion is to read the whole number into a buffer (string) and then call [`atoi`](http://www.codecogs.com/reference/computing/c/stdlib.h/atoi.php). Make triple sure that the string is properly null-terminated.

Answer (score 0):

One solution, I won't say it's good or bad in your case since you don't provide any code, but you could do something like this: (pseudoish code)

```
int i;
int val = 0;
char *string = "5238785";
for (i = 0; i < strlen(string); i++) {
    val = val * 10 + atoi(string[i]);
}
```

**NOTE**: I simplified it and you should do more string controls to make sure you don't go out of bounds etc. Make sure the string is NULL-terminated `\0`, but the concept is that you read one digit at the time, and just move what you've read so far "one step left" to fit next digit.